# SP/O365 Library: document version history shows wrong username

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, user-accounts, version-history

Has anyone else experienced this? We are O365/hosted SharePoint. I honestly didn't believe it when it was reported to me by other users, but now I've seen it for myself. The version history (showing document saves) in a library sometimes shows the wrong username - in this instance me, even though I did not have the document open, instead of the user whom I know to have been working in the file, alone, at the time of those saves. I *did* have the document open previously today, but had long since closed out of MS Word completely. Most of us are in Win10 and we only use the full client application of Word, not Word Online (for a host of other unrelated reasons).

Is this a bug? Is there a fix? It is making collaborators in other departments uneasy - and we have enough trouble with SP adoption.

Comment: Do you have any workflows that you created running on the library?

Comment: When you said the wrong username, does that mean the other person's saves had your name in the history or your name appeared in between the saves of the other person? Also, have you synced this folder locally somewhere in your machine?

Comment: It shows my name only for the other person's saves across several hours. I don't have libraries synced locally. The only workflow that affects this library is one that creates folders for a new project based on creation of a record in a list.

Comment: are you opening the document in edit mode ? 
i would enable "require check out to edit document" on the library settings

Comment: we open directly in Word (not Word Online). We try not to use the check out unless we absolutely have to because generally multiple people need to review and edit at the same time. This seems to be a rare glitch- this is the first I've seen it and we do hundreds of files each with a team of 5-7 working on them all the time.

Comment: Was there any solution found for this problem? We are seeing this issue for few libraries but there is no workflow attached, and version history seen from native office client is displaying perfectly.

Comment: @Techie - No solution yet to my knowledge. We still experience this periodically two years later but I can't replicate it on demand for tech support.